# Format a database for recurring tournament scores for multiple people

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Looking for some help and ideas on how to format a database more efficiently.

I am making a database/website for our club's recurring weekly tournaments. We have around 300 members total, each weekly tournament can have anywhere between 20-70 players. Right now I have the tables like this:

**Players** Table:

id  |  name

**Scores** Table:

id(tournament id) | date | park | td | scores

both id's are just unique A_I individually, the td(tournament director) is just their id from 'Players' table which I've already had enough trouble writing multiple SQL queries to get the td(id) and then query for the TD's name.

and scores is my problem. I have it being inputted as: id,score;id,score;etc..

So I have to re-query to get the players name from their ID. I want people to be able to see each tournaments page, as well as each individual player to have their own "Profile" page to show all their scores. I know it can be done but it seems so in-efficient to explode each tournaments score to search for only their ID. There's got to be a better way.

Heeeellp

Comment: Your scores table should become your tournament table, and the scores column there should become a new scores table, with columns for tournament id, player id, and score.

Comment: " re-query to get the players name from their ID" that is where you would use a join

Comment: just starting to learn about joins. I'm only use to basic SQL right now

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean. So I can select by any of those factors. Jeez, I feel dumb

Comment: you most definitely will need to use joins here

Comment: It doesn't get more basic than joins.

Comment: Thanks, Strawberry. Very helpful.